# Build error occured when I build with Unreal Engine Development Editor mode

Tags: c++, build, unreal-engine5

[image]
“확인할 수 없는 외부 기호” means unresolved external reference.
It’s okay when I build with debug game editor, but this errors keep appears when I try to build with Development Editor mode. I didn’t do any modification about engine source.

Refresh Rider Project or Generate visual studio project file kind of things helps nothing...

is there any solution about this? why this happens?

Comment: do you mean "undefined reference"? I suggest to change the ide to English then you have better search experience. There are tons of reasons for "undefined reference". Most common one is missing lib in linker. Check your both of build configs

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]? See [ask] for further guidance. Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete Binary and intermedate folder in project and rebuild is helps.
now it works well.